# How to make Adobe Reader 9 open PDF's in new window?

Tags: windows, linux, pdf, adobe-reader

Now when I open two PDF's its opened in the same window and in two tabs. this is very annoying.

how to make it open in different Windows?

P.S. I would like to do it on Windows XP and on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
acroread 1.pdf & acroread -openInNewInstance 2.pdf
```